# How can I get Mupen64 and my game saves on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, emulation

I recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, and I had a bunch of game progresses saved from my Mupen64 emulator. I kept my roms, so I figure I kept my saves as well, but I can't find Mupen64 in the repository, and when I tried downloading it online, it crashed and wouldn't load again. Is there another version of the emulator I can get? or another emulator which will read my game saves from Mupen?

Answer (score 1):

The emulator is on repositories. Click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/mupen64plus) or paste this on terminal: `sudo apt-get install mupen64plus`.

Comment: I had the emulator installed fine, but the game saves weren't there. Also, is there anyway to revert back to 11.10 from 12.04 and keep everything I had before?